# how to print out double quoted statement with variables in perl

Tags: perl

I need some perl help trying to print this double quoted statement with variables, mixed with some unix sed commands that I can't seem to escape properly.

I am not interested in executing it, but just want to print this out to a file. Thanks for your help.

```
print  MYOUTFILE "mysql -u foo -pbar --database $dbsrc -h $node --port 3306 -ss -e \"SELECT 'a','b','c' UNION SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM $tblist limit 10\" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > myDump.csv\"\n"`;
```

In particular this part is giving me a problem:  `| sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > myDump.csv\"\n";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reduce **escape complications**, use `q` and `qq` when needed:

```
print  MYOUTFILE qq{mysql -u foo -pbar --database $dbsrc -h $node --port 3306 -ss -e "SELECT 'a','b','c' UNION SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM $tblist limit 10"}, q{ | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > myDump.csv}, "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `qq{string}` instead of `"string"` to create an interpolated string that doesn't require double quote characters to be escaped. It makes things much easier to manage.

Comment: i tried it. `qq{string}\n`, no luck. it doesn't like the `$` in that sed statement

Comment: `$` means "Start of a scalar", you still have to escape it with a slash.

Comment: escaped it as well. still no luck. i tried escaping `\t` and `\s` too.

Comment: got it to work, except for newline. i tried `qq{string}"\n";` and `qq{string}\n";`

Comment: @jdamae - just FYI, the `qq{...}` is a string in itself, you would need to concatenate the `"\n"`, i.e. `print qq{...} . "\n";` (although in this case putting the slash-n inside the qq{} is obviously better.